# Overlapping <div>

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<div id="data_div">
    <!-- render content here, might take a while... -->
</div>
<div id="loading_div" style="background-color:cyan" >
    Loading, please wait...
</div>
```

I would like that "loading_div" overlap "data_div" to create the effect that loading is in progress, while what is really happening is that contents are being already rendered in the background. When the document is ready, then I can do something like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#loading_div").hide();
}
```

How can this be implemented with CSS and/or JQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For #loading_div, assuming it's not inside a wrapper or something (and preferably *above* #data_div in terms of your code):

```
#loading_div {
margin: 10%;
width: 80%;
height: 50%;
text-align: center;
opacity: 0.8;
z-index: 99;
background: black;
color: white;
display: block;
position: absolute;
padding-top: 30%;
}

#data_div {
 z-index: 0;   
    text-align: center;
}
```

Modify to taste...

http://jsfiddle.net/H2WWx/

Answer (score 0):

Just position the loading div on top of the data div. You can do this by setting:

```
#loading_div {
position: relative;
top: xx;
left: xx;
}
```

where the top and left properties have the necessary values needed to shift the loading div to cover the data div.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the right idea. First you will want to position your loading_div over the data_div using CSS positioning.

Secondly, you will want to use $(window).load(); which waits until all resources, scripts, and images are loaded. $(document).ready() fires when the DOM is ready which is way before that.

Here is an example using jQuery to position the loading div over your content. A benefit of using jQuery is that it's a progressive enhancement, meaning it's safe for non-js devices:

http://jsfiddle.net/eAfHm/

Answer (score 0):

I would use $(window).load(); instead of ready, this will wait until really EVERYTHING is done.

```
 #loading_div{
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
     height:100%;
     z-index: 9999;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help : http://jsfiddle.net/SQHgu/11/, although cross domain request are not allowed (for example only).

Answer (score 0):

Why make the code yourself when there is a great automatic preloader on the internet to be found:
http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/queryloader-preload-your-website-in-style/

I use this preloader quite a lot. Nice animation and it works crossbrowser. You can edit the CSS easily and it is simple to implement.